# How to pass boolean values as paramters thorugh addeventlistener js

Tags: javascript, boolean, addeventlistener

I have different buttons and depending on what button is pressed, i want the variables in my function to change.

css:

```
.build{
    border-radius:50%;
    height:85px;
    width:85px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#build1{
    margin-left:372px;
    margin-top:320px;
    
}
```

html:

```
<button class="build" id="build1"></button>
```

Rest is javascript

Some variables

```
var build1EL=document.querySelector("#build1");
var buildtower1=false;
var click1=false;
var a1=false;
var mynter=100;
build1EL.addEventListener("click",clicktower);
```

A function

```
function clicktower(){

if(byggtaarn1===false){
    if(coins>=75){
        coins-=75;
        byggtaarn1=true;
        a1=true;
    }
}
if(click1===true){
    click1=false;
    a1=false;
}
if(a1===true){
    click1=true;
}
tower1();
a1=true;
}
```

Then this works perfectly fine, tower1() is another function and the inside of the function is kinda messy, but it works. But i must do this 5 more times, but with different buttons and a corresponding buildtower, click and a-variable

So keeping the same variables for the first button, and change the function and addeventlistener  to this:

`build1EL.addEventListener("click", function(){ clicktower(buildtower1, click1,a1); });`

```
function clicktower(buildtower,click,a){

if(buildtower===false){
    if(coins>=75){
        coins-=75;
        buildtower=true;
        a=true;
    }
}
if(click===true){
    click=false;
    a=false;
}
if(a===true){
    click=true;
}
taarn1();
a=true;}
```

But this doesnt work, i tried different ways to get the addeventlistener to work with arguments, but none worked.

Comment: Are you adding the event listener when the DOM is fully created?

Comment: Your code has multiple problems. For example, the X,Y position is hard coded into the css.  So if you create more than one they will all be on top of each other.  It would probably help to work through some tutorials on creating and using objects. And once you define your object it will be easy to create as many instances as you need, each with their own properties and event handlers.  See: [MDN - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: The X,Y position will be different for each button, thats why the class is same for the rest, and ill create an individual ID with only X,Y position for  each button